# How to update radio button in view from viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism

Say I have a few radio buttons grouped together in my view.xaml:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Item1" Command="{Binding ChangeRadioSelectionCommand}" CommandParameter="Item1" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Item2" Command="{Binding ChangeRadioSelectionCommand}" CommandParameter="Item2" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Item3" Command="{Binding ChangeRadioSelectionCommand}" CommandParameter="Item3" />
```

Then in my `viewmodel.cs` I have something like:

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
  private string radioSelection = "Item1";
  public string RadioSelection
  {
    get { return this.radioSelection; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this.radioSelection, value); }
  }

  public ViewModel() 
  {
    this.ChangeRadioSelectionCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(this.OnChangeRadioSelection, this.CanChangeRadioSelection);
  }

  public ICommand ChangeRadioSelectionCommand { get; private set; }
  private void OnChangeRadioSelection(string radioSelection)
  {
    RadioSelection = radioSelection;
  }
  private bool CanChangeRadioSelection(string radioSelection) { return true; }
}
```

This works fine for getting values from the view into the viewmodel, but how would I go from the viewmodel to the view if something changes in the viewmodel. For simplicity, let's say I add a button to the xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ResetRadioSelectionCommand}" />
```

All it would do is reset the radio selection to the first item and so the `viewmodel.cs` would look something like:

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
  private string radioSelection = "Item1";
  public string RadioSelection
  {
    get { return this.radioSelection; }
    set { SetProperty(ref this.radioSelection, value); }
  }

  public ViewModel() 
  {
    this.ChangeRadioSelectionCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(this.OnChangeRadioSelection, this.CanChangeRadioSelection);
    this.ResetRadioSelectionCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnResetRadioSelection, this.CanResetRadioSelection);
  }

  public ICommand ChangeRadioSelectionCommand { get; private set; }
  private void OnChangeRadioSelection(string radioSelection)
  {
    RadioSelection = radioSelection;
  }
  private bool CanChangeRadioSelection(string radioSelection) { return true; }

  public ICommand ResetRadioSelectionCommand { get; private set; }
  private void OnResetRadioSelection()
  {
    RadioSelection = "Item1";
  }
  private bool CanResetRadioSelection() { return true; }
}
```

This would change radioSelection, but it won't reflect in the gui. Is there a way to do this? Or perhaps just a better way to deal with radio buttons in general?

Answer (score 2):

It is completely the wrong way. Your ViewModel should contain a sensible property with sensible name. For example, CurrentMode.

**FIRST SOLUTION**

ViewModel

```
public enum DisplayMode { Vertical, Horizontal, Diagonal }

private DisplayMode currentMode;
public DisplayMode CurrentMode
{
    get { return currentMode; }
    set { SetProperty(ref currentMode, value); }
}
```

And now you can bind this property to [RadioButton.IsChecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) via [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Vertical" IsChecked="{Binding CurrentMode, Converter={StaticResource enumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Vertical}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Horizontal" IsChecked="{Binding CurrentMode, Converter={StaticResource enumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Horizontal}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Group" Content="Diagonal" IsChecked="{Binding CurrentMode, Converter={StaticResource enumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Diagonal}" />
```

Converter is generic for all enums. You need to add it to your project and declare in resource-block of your view.

```
public class EnumBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        object parameterValue = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), parameterString);

        return parameterValue.Equals(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

It's one of many solutions. You may not want to us enum for your property because the subject area is not mapped to enumeration of parameters. Then you can bind to text value:

**SECOND SOLUTION**

ViewModel

```
private string currentMode;
public string CurrentMode
{
    get { return currentMode; }
    set { SetProperty(ref currentMode, value); }
}
```

View

```
<RadioButton Name="RadioButton1"
                     GroupName="Group"
                     Content="Vertical"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentMode, Converter={StaticResource boolToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Vertical}" />
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton2"
                     GroupName="Group"
                     Content="Horizontal"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentMode, Converter={StaticResource boolToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Horizontal}" />
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton3"
                     GroupName="Group"
                     Content="Diagonal"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentMode, Converter={StaticResource boolToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Diagonal}" />
```

Converter

```
public class BooleanToStringValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToString(value).Equals(System.Convert.ToString(parameter)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The general principle is to store meaningful projection of the subject area in ViewModels. There is no many sense if you'll keep store copy of view properties in your ViewModel. RadioSelection is a senseless name and it can't be correlated to model without additional commentaries.

Comment: what do you mean by "Your ViewModel should contain a sensible property with sensible name"? is the converter method still necessary these days with the prism mvvm practices and patterns?

Comment: 1. I mean that property names should be clear in terms of the subject area instead of terms of your view (like Button, Radio group and etc.) 
2. Yes converters is the main part of mvvm application regardless of frameworks like Prism, mvvm-light or others.

Comment: ya, i just gave generic names since it was just an example. i stumbled upon [a page that suggests using radios as a checkbox, overriding onchecked and ontoggled, or using radios as a list](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/issue-with-radiobuttons-and-binding-for.html) as a way to get around the binding issues with radio buttons. do you have any opinions on these methods?

Comment: I'm not sure I remember this issue. .net 4.0 existed for 5 years and WinXP supports .net 4.0 then I probably never used wpf with .net 3.5 because used winforms until 2011. But the article contains few solutions and didn't they fit? Chckboxes with custom templates can become a problem in future but inherited radiobutton with inherited style is not a problem, isn't it?